# How to use `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`: without getting Incompatible Shapes Error

Tags: tensorflow, julia

I would like to use the [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.md)
with the julia TensorFlow wrapper.

The operations is defined in the [code here](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/blob/1127fb5864b6513924f8c44cacc46102189fabc5/src/ops/nn.jl#L201).
Basically, as I understand it the first argument should be logits, that would normally be fed to softmax to get them to be category probabilities (~1hot output).
And the second should be the correct labels as label ids.

I have adjusted the example code from the [TensorFlow.jl readme](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/tree/94303d4541785da283cff7fd0039a98a5ad6ff94)
See below:

```
using Distributions
using TensorFlow

# Generate some synthetic data
x = randn(100, 50)
w = randn(50, 10)
y_prob = exp(x*w)
y_prob ./= sum(y_prob,2)

function draw(probs)
    y = zeros(size(probs))
    for i in 1:size(probs, 1)
        idx = rand(Categorical(probs[i, :]))
        y[i, idx] = 1
    end
    return y
end

y = draw(y_prob)

# Build the model
sess = Session(Graph())
X = placeholder(Float64)
Y_obs = placeholder(Float64)
Y_obs_lbl = indmax(Y_obs, 2)
variable_scope("logisitic_model", initializer=Normal(0, .001)) do
    global W = get_variable("weights", [50, 10], Float64)
    global B = get_variable("bias", [10], Float64)
end

L = X*W + B
Y=nn.softmax(L)
#costs = log(Y).*Y_obs #Dense (Orginal) way
costs = nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(L, Y_obs_lbl+1) #sparse way
Loss = -reduce_sum(costs)
optimizer = train.AdamOptimizer()
minimize_op = train.minimize(optimizer, Loss)
saver = train.Saver()
# Run training
run(sess, initialize_all_variables())
cur_loss, _ = run(sess, [Loss, minimize_op], Dict(X=>x, Y_obs=>y))
```

When I run it however, I get an error:

```
Tensorflow error: Status: Incompatible shapes: [1,100] vs. [100,10]
     [[Node: gradients/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_10_grad/mul = Mul[T=DT_DOUBLE, _class=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_10_grad/ExpandDims, SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_10:1)]]


 in check_status(::TensorFlow.Status) at /home/ubuntu/.julia/v0.5/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:101
 in run(::TensorFlow.Session, ::Array{TensorFlow.Port,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{TensorFlow.Port,1}, ::Array{Ptr{Void},1}) at /home/ubuntu/.julia/v0.5/TensorFlow/src/run.jl:96
 in run(::TensorFlow.Session, ::Array{TensorFlow.Tensor,1}, ::Dict{TensorFlow.Tensor,Array{Float64,2}}) at /home/ubuntu/.julia/v0.5/TensorFlow/src/run.jl:143
```

This only happens when I try to train it.
If I don't include an optimise function/output then it works fine.
So I am doing something that screws up the gradient math.

Comment: I have raised an issue: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/124

Comment: Ok, it is a bug. It is being fixed.